# bash delete directories based on contents

Tags: bash, directory, file-manipulation

Currently I have multiple directories

```
Directory1 Directory2 Directory3 Directory4
```

each of these directories contain files (the files are somewhat cryptic)

what i wish to do is scan files within the folders to see if certain files are present, if they are then leave that folder alone, if the certain files are not present then just delete the entire directory. here is what i mean:

im searching for the files that have the word .pass. in the filename.
Say Directory 4 has that file that im looking for

```
Direcotry4:    
file1.temp.pass.exmpl
file1.temp.exmpl
file1.tmp
```

and the rest of the Directories do not have that specific file:

```
file.temp
file.exmp
file.tmp.other
```

so i would like to delete Directory1,2 and3 But only keep Directory 4...

So far i have come up with this code

(arr is a array of all the directory names)

```
for x in ${arr[@]}
do
    find $x -type f ! -name "*pass*" -exec rd {} $x\;
done
```

another way i have thought of doing this is like this:

```
for x in ${arr[@]}
do

    cd $x find . -type f ! -name "*Pass*" | xargs -i rd {} $x/
done
```

SO far these don't seem to work, and im scared that i might do something wrong and have all my files deleted.....(i have backed up)

is there any way that i can do this? remember i want Directory 4 to be unchanged, everything in it i want to keep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if your directory contains a pass file:

```
if [ "" = "$(find directory -iname '*pass*' -type f |  head -n 1)" ]
  then
    echo notfound
  else
    echo found
fi
```

To do that in a loop:

```
for x in "${arr[@]}"
  do
      if [ "" = "$(find "$x" -iname '*pass*' -type f |  head -n 1)" ]
        then
          rm -rf "$x"
      fi
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# arr is a array of all the directory names
for x in ${arr[@]}
do
ret=$(find "$x" -type f -name "*pass*" -exec echo "0" \;)
# expect zero length $ret value to remove directory
if [ -z "$ret" ]; then
    # remove dir
    rm -rf "$x"
fi
done
```